# Javascript Regex - Compare 2 last pair of chars

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string like this (Phone number) :

```
0223216582
```

And I want to check if the two last pairs of number (65 and 82) are **not equals** :

Actually, my regex returns true if its equals, but this is not what I really need :

```
console.log(/^02.*(\d{2})\1$/.test('0223216582')); // false
console.log(/^02.*(\d{2})\1$/.test('0223216565')); // true
```

I need something like this :

```
console.log(/<regex>/.test('0223216582')); // true
console.log(/<regex>/.test('0223216565')); // false
```

**EDIT**

I will use this Regex inside a MongoDB request, like this :

```
this.findOne({
    used: {$eq: false},
    number: {$regex: /^02.*(\d{2})\1$/}
});
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just invert the result of the regex?

`console.log(!(/^02.*(\d{2})\1$/.test('0223216582')));` and
`console.log(!(/^02.*(\d{2})\1$/.test('0223216565')));`
 
should do exactly what you want.

Comment: This regex is used to filter a mongoDB request, check my edit ^^

Comment: Ah, that explains this, as well as why you don't use the string methods of js here. In that case, you should take a look at the very promising solution of anubhava. Don't forget to mark his answer as accepted if it works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
^02.*(\d{2})(?!\1$)\d{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qt1feR/2)

This will return a match only when last 2 digits are not equal to previous 2 digits.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `02`: Match digits `02`:
- `.*`: Match 0 or more characters
- `(\d{2})`: Match 2 digits and capture it in group #1
- `(?!\1$)`: Negative lookahead condition to assert than next 2 digits are not same as in capture group #1
- `\d{2}`: Match last 2 digits
- `$`: End

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the need for a regex here. You could simply get the last two digit of both number and compare them using a normal string comparaison :

```
function comparePhone(ph1, ph2) {
    return ph1.splice(-2) !== ph2.splice(-2);
}
```

Here, the splice function returns a substring of the original. In our case, we are selecting the last two char ( -2 )

Comment: This regex is used to filter a mongoDB request, I can't just get all the data and filter by myself with a condition like this :/

Comment: I understand, i will still leave my answer here but will highly recommand [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58732736/5784924) in your case.

Comment: You should also edit your question to reflect the fact that you need this to filter a mongoDB query, it will be more relevent for people having the same issue. @Sparw

Answer (score 0):

I would use arithmetic here:

```js
var number = 223212255;
if ( (Math.floor(number / 1000) % 10 == Math.floor(number / 100) % 10) &&
     (Math.floor(number / 10) % 10 == number % 10 )) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

This solution might be more performant than a regex based solution.

Comment: This regex is used to filter a mongoDB request, check my edit ^^

Comment: How does that change your question?